# Yet another Iframe not responsive Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

http://billsanddiamonds.com/v2/stack.html

I'm trying to acheive the above and below without the iframe being cut off thus allowing it to expand visibly.

Here we have successfully thrown the iframe into our document, however after searching I have not resolved the function AdjustIframeHeightOnLoad()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AdjustIframeHeightOnLoad() { document.getElementById("form-iframe").style.height = document.getElementById("form-iframe").contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px"; }
function AdjustIframeHeight(i) { document.getElementById("form-iframe").style.height = parseInt(i) + "px"; }
</script>
```

May be going about javascript the wrong way here but what seems to be happening is the iframe is returning an error.

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "hxxp://billsanddiamonds.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "hxxp://www.billsanddiamonds.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must
>   match.

My research has led me to learn maybe I just don't understand the cross-domain iframe resize issue although all things are coming from the same domain.

Comment: Pretty much exactly what the error says. `www.foo.com` is not the same as `foo.com`.

Comment: I would also try and talk you into using something other than a frame. There are several alternatives depending on what you wanted it to do and look like.

Comment: How is that possible. Currently 
`src="http://foo.com/"` was changed to 
`src="http://www.foo.com/"` it's still returning the same error.  Would it make more sense to change document.getElementById ?